# Chromium browser kiosk mode

Tags: chromium, kiosk, youtube

I'm using chromium browser in kiosk mode to display a web page (Raspberry Pi 3b).

I'm using this for professional purpose, this means that once I sell it to customer, it is expected to work smoothly (atleast for say 5-10 years).

I've following doubts regarding chromium browser and it's extension before I sell it out:

1. **Chromium version**: will chromium version am using right now will become obsolete in coming years?
2. **Cookie**: will cookie value be retained over years?
3. **Extension**: will extension am using be obsolete over coming years?
4. **YouTube Iframe Player**: I'm using YouTube Iframe Player to display video in short intervals through JavaScript. Can there be any changes in YouTube Iframe Player so that current setting in chromium will face issue to carry out the function?
5. Apart from above is there anything else I need to worry about?

Comment: You are asking 5 general questions in one. This is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. You may visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea what questions should be asked.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a note you may want to not use Raspberry Pi's for this purpose, they will need more maintenance (SD cards die), however, this is completely possible. So, I would recommend making a clone of the SD card and be prepared to service the kiosks or ensure there is at least a semi-technical person (just in case there is an issue) Maybe stock pile spare SD cards, and try to use Ethernet.

1. Chromium can **automatically** update, this will be fine. Maybe set the Pi, to power down overnight, then power on in the morning. This will allow for automatic updates as Chromium will restart.
2. What are you displaying that needs cookies? I have read that you are using YouTube (is the video gonna be made Private, then it might be worth making the videos public or unlisted, then you don't need to worry about cookies)
3. You wouldn't need an extension unless it was for another purpose.
4. That should be fine, however, if it is possible, look into hosting the videos on the  Pi itself or a server on the LAN if there is multiple Pis have one host the videos? What if the internet went down, you wouldn't have any videos right?
5. Are the videos going to be the only thing on the screen? If so maybe look into running a video player (such as VLC) set a playlist and run the videos from there?

Have a nice day!
*Josh*

Comment: I've made pi to read only mode, which means that it'll reset itself after restart. Cookie is used to detect user and display his content by id. Some extensions are used to display unicode fonts. It is designed so as to display video in web page itself through YouTube. No, video+user's data are displayed in intervals.

Comment: Fair enough, if you are setting the Pi to reset on boot, you may not be able to store the cookies, as they would be cleared. I am not familiar with using a Pi in read only mode.